# Rails update associated model's object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

My Opportunity model looks like this:

```
class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord

# opportunity belongs to a user
belongs_to :user

def self.create_opportunity(params)

  # Fetch opportunity params and user params from request parameters
  opportunity_params = params[:opportunity_params]
  user_params = params[:user_params]

  opportunity = Opportunity.find_or_initialize_by(id: opportunity_params[:id])
  opportunity.assign_attributes(opportunity_params)

  opportunity.user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: user_params[:email])
  opportunity.user.assign_attributes(user_params)

  opportunity.save

end
```

user.rb model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # validate user email
  validates :email, presence: true, email: true
  enum gender: { male:1, female:2 }

end
```

We create a new user if a user with the email provided does not exists. This works well when a new user is created, but doesn't work when there already is a user. The update for user model doesn't work. 
For update on user to work, I need to specifically call `opportunity.user.save`

Any idea how to make this work without explicitly calling save on user model?

Answer (score 0):

With this line you can create a new user if it does not exist and update its data.

```
opportunity.user.find_or_create_by(email: user_params[:email]).update(user_params)
```

This method will return true/false if the user has been updated or not. If you want the user created itself use this:

```
opportunity.user.find_or_create_by(email: user_params[:email]).tap{ |user| user.update(user_params) }
```

edit:
THIS HAS TO WORK:

```
opportunity.user = User.find_or_create_by(email: user_params[:email]).tap{ |user| user.update(user_params) }
```

Comment: Produces this error: undefined method `find_or_create_by' for #<User:0x007fc108039f78>

Comment: User is child of ActiveRecord::Base ??http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

Comment: it works, but it seems to be a two step process, it creates a new user with given email, and then updates it with other data. This makes two db queries which is not how I would like to go about it.